# Python numpy grid transformation using universal functions

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

Here is my problem : I manipulate `432*46*136*136` grids representing `time*(space)` encompassed in numpy arrays with numpy and python. I have one array `alt`, which encompasses the altitudes of the grid points, and another array `temp` which stores the temperature of the grid points.

It is problematic for a comparison : if `T1` and `T2` are two results, `T1[t0,z0,x0,y0]` and `T2[t0,z0,x0,y0]` represent the temperature at `H1[t0,z0,x0,y0]` and `H2[t0,z0,x0,y0]` meters, respectively. But I want to compare the temperature of points at the same altitude, not at the same grid point.

Hence I want to modify the z-axis of my matrices to represent the altitude and not the grid point. I create a function `conv(alt[t,z,x,y])` which attributes a number between -20 and 200 to each altitude. Here is my code :

```
def interpolation_extended(self,temp,alt):
    [t,z,x,y]=temp.shape
    new=np.zeros([t,220,x,y])
    for l in range(0,t):
       for j in range(0,z):
          for lat in range(0,x):
             for lon in range(0,y):
                new[l,conv(alt[l,j,lat,lon]),lat,lon]=temp[l,j,lat,lon]
    return new
```

But this takes definitely too much time, I can't work this it. I tried to write it using universal functions with numpy :

```
def interpolation_extended(self,temp,alt):
    [t,z,x,y]=temp.shape
    new=np.zeros([t,220,x,y])
    for j in range(0,z):
       new[:,conv(alt[:,j,:,:]),:,:]=temp[:,j,:,:]
    return new
```

But that does not work. Do you have any idea of doing this in python/numpy without using 4 nested loops ?

Thank you

Comment: That might be because function calls in Python are costly. Precalculating the `conv` coordinate with e.g. `fromfunction` numpy method might help.

Comment: Is z larger than 220? If that is the case I can see why your code would crash.

Comment: Is `conv` any linear combination/function of `alt`? Can you give an example or post your code for `conv`? If `conv` can be vectorized, you can write it in 1 liner.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. No, `z` is between **0** and **46**. My altitudes are between **-10.000m** and **+100.000m**, so `conv` is in fact just : `round(alt[t,z,x,y]/500.)` (I made a mistake, `conv` takes values between **-20** and **200**, and not between **0** and **220**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really try the code since I don't have your matrices, but something like this should do the job.

First, instead of declaring `conv` as a function, get the whole altitude projection for all your data:

```
conv = np.round(alt / 500.).astype(int)
```

Using `np.round`, the numpys version of round, it rounds all the elements of the matrix by vectorizing operations in C, and thus, you get a new array very quickly (at C speed). The following line aligns the altitudes to start in 0, by shifting all the array by its minimum value (in your case, -20):

```
conv -= conv.min()
```

the line above would transform your altitude matrix from [-20, 200] to [0, 220] (better for indexing).

With that, interpolation can be done easily by getting multidimensional indices:

```
t, z, y, x = np.indices(temp.shape)
```

the **vectors** above contain all the indices needed to index your original matrix. You can then create the new matrix by doing:

```
new_matrix[t, conv[t, z, y, x], y, x] = temp[t, z, y, x]
```

without any loop at all.

Let me know if it works. It might give you some erros since is hard for me to test it without data, but it should do the job.

---

The following toy example works fine:

```
A = np.random.randn(3,4,5) # Random 3x4x5 matrix -- your temp matrix
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, 3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5) # your conv matrix with altitudes from 0 to 9
C = np.zeros((3,10,5)) # your new matrix

z, y, x = np.indices(A.shape)
C[z, B[z, y, x], x] = A[z, y, x]
```

`C` contains your results by altitude.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much. I didn't even know about the possibility to work with indices as vectors. I had to change : `conv = np.round(alt / 500.)` to `conv = np.round(alt / 500.).astype(int)` to use conv as indices.

Comment: @Arnaud PROST thanks! Already edited. Vector indices are very useful. For example: `A[[3, 7, 8], :]` (for `A` 2D array) will return the 4th, 8th and 9th rows of the matrix. The answer using `np.indices` is an extension to that by indexing all the elements of all axis in a multidimensional array.